# Using additional data in php exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I have php code that execute python cgi and I want to pass python trace (returned from cgi) as extra data to php exception how can I do this and how can I get that value from `catch(Exception e) {` (It should check if that extra value exesit or not).

I have code like this:

```
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
if (isset($response->error)) {
    // how to send $response->trace with exception.
    throw new Exception($response->error);
}
return $response->result;
```

and I use json-rpc library that should return that data to the user:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //catch all exeption from user code
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
    echo response(null, $id, array("code"=>200, "message"=>$msg));
}
```

Do I need to write new type of exception or can I do this with normal `Exception`? I would like to send everything that was thrown in `"data" =>`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to extend Exception class:

```
<?php

class ResponseException extends Exception 
{
    private $_data = '';

    public function __construct($message, $data) 
    {
        $this->_data = $data;
        parent::__construct($message);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->_data;
    }
}
```

When throwing:

```
<?php

...
throw new ResponseException($response->error, $someData);
...
```

And when catching:

```
catch(ResponseException $e) {
    ...
    $data = $e->getData();
    ...
}
```

### Dynamic Property (not recommended)

Please **note** that this will cause deprecation error in PHP 8.2 and will **stop working in PHP 9** according to one of the PHP RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties

As the OP asking about doing this task without extending `Exception` class, you can totally skip `ResponseException` class declaration. I really not recommend do it this way, unless you've got really strong reason (see this topic for more details: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186439/is-declaring-fields-on-classes-actually-harmful-in-php)

In throwing section:

```
...
$e = new Exception('Exception message');
$e->data = $customData; // we're creating object property on the fly
throw $e;
...
```

and when catching:

```
catch(Exception $e) {
    $data = $e->data; // Access data property
}
```

September 2018 edit:
As some of readers found this answer useful, I have added a link to another Stack Overflow question which explains the downsides of using dynamically declared properties.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without new Exception type, what will work with generic Exception (when catch)?

Comment: Doesn’t extending `Exception` this way violate LSP as it changes the constructor signature?

Comment: plus 1 for dirty way

Comment: @Glutexo not sure what do you mean by that? Exception class constructor has other optional parameters but you are not required to pass them when extending.

Comment: First off, I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you! (I never knew how to extend classes, let alone a native class.) Second: I found I was able to write my catch as `catch(Exception $e)` and I was still able to successfully call the `$e->getData()` method. Why is this? I thought you'd have to refer to the extended  `ResponseException` class.

Comment: Found the answer from [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#68697) in the php exceptions manual: *"If you want to catch **any** exception, no matter what the type, just use `catch(Exception $var)`, because all exceptions are sub-classes of the built-in Exception."*

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code converts the response text directly into an object without any intermediate step. Instead, you could always just keep the serialized (via JSON) text it and append it to the end of the Exception message.

```php
$responseText = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($responseText);
if (isset($response->error)) {
    throw new Exception('Error when fetching resource. Response:'.$responseText);
}
return $response->result;
```

Then you could just recover everything after "Response:" in your error log and optionally de-serialize it or just read it.

As an aside, I would also not count on the server sending JSON, you should verify that the response text was actually parseable as JSON and return a separate error for that if it isn't.